# Java Swing HTML JEditorPane causes "Windows Background Sound" to play when pressing Enter

Tags: java, windows, swing, audio, jeditorpane

I would like to create a `JFrame` with an HTML `JEditorPane`.
There are certain things that need to happen when the user presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

However, as long as I keep the `JEditorPane`, a "Windows Background Sound" plays whenever <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed. The sound can be heard in this YouTube video at 2:57:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRTvrtuuGJQ&t=176s

I want the `JEditorPane` but I don't want the sound.
How do I remove the sound?

Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create Frame with dimensions
    Dimension frameDimension = new Dimension(600, 400);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(frameDimension);
    frame.setSize(frameDimension);
    frame.setBackground(Color.white);


    //Create HTML Editor Pane
    JEditorPane htmlLabel = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
    htmlLabel.setEditable(false);
    htmlLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    htmlLabel.setFont(new Font(htmlLabel.getName(), Font.PLAIN, 14));
    htmlLabel.setVisible(true);


    //IF I KEEP THIS LINE,
    //I will hear a "Windows Notification Sound"
    //whenever I press ENTER
    frame.add(htmlLabel);
    //I don't want the sound but I want this pane


    htmlLabel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            //If Enter is pressed
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 10) {
                // DO STUFF
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

By the way, my Java Version is 1.8 u221

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You get the sound probably because of `htmlLabel.setEditable(false);`. Perhaps an additional `htmlLabel.setFocusable(false);` helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### TL;DR

You need to remove the [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Action.html) associated with pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

```java
htmlLabel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed ENTER"), "none");
```

##### Explanation

`JEditorPane` associates pressing of combinations of keyboard keys with actions. This code shows all the registered combinations:

```java
for (KeyStroke ks : htmlLabel.getInputMap().allKeys()) {
    System.out.println(ks);
}
```

One of the lines of output, when running the above code, is:

```
pressed ENTER
```

The [default] `Action` associated with pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> can be obtained like so:

```java
htmlLabel.getActionMap().get(htmlLabel.getInputMap().get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed ENTER")));
```

This returns an instance of class `javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit.StyledInsertBreakAction`. That class's `actionPerformed` method contains the following code:

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JEditorPane target = getEditor(e);

    if (target != null) {
        if ((!target.isEditable()) || (!target.isEnabled())) {
            UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(target);
            return;
        }
```

In other words, if the `JEditorPane` is not editable and the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is pressed, the [Windows] *beep* sound will be played.

Hence, as written above, the simplest solution (in my opinion) is to simply remove the `Action` associated with pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Of-course, you could, alternatively, create your own `Action` to replace the default one.

Note that your `KeyListener` still works, i.e. even after removing the `Action`, pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> still invokes method `keyPressed`.

Refer to

- [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)
- [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Both are from *Using Swing Components* lesson in *Creating a GUI With Swing* trail of Oracle's Java tutorials.

Here is my rewrite of the code in your question:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension frameDimension = new Dimension(600, 400);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(frameDimension);
        frame.setSize(frameDimension);
        frame.setBackground(Color.white);

        // Create HTML Editor Pane
        JEditorPane htmlLabel = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
        htmlLabel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed ENTER"), "none");
        htmlLabel.setEditable(false);
        htmlLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        htmlLabel.setFont(new Font(htmlLabel.getName(), Font.PLAIN, 14));
        htmlLabel.setVisible(true);

        // IF I KEEP THIS LINE,
        // I will hear a "Windows Notification Sound"
        // whenever I press ENTER
        frame.add(htmlLabel);
        // I don't want the sound but I want this pane

        htmlLabel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // If Enter is pressed
                if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) {
                    // DO STUFF
                    System.out.println("ENTER");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            }
        });
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```